# Reading JSON value without using JsonNode

Tags: java, fasterxml

Example JSON format as follow:

```json
{
  myarray: [
    {
      id: 123,
      title: "my title",
      name: "my name"
    },
    {
      id: 456,
      title: "my title 2",
      name: "my name 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using the above JSON, we were getting `myarray` using the following code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(con.getInputStream(), JsonNode.class);
def stations = mapper.readValue(node.get("myarray"), MyClass[].class);
```

After a few days we upgrade json library and throwing the following exceptins.

```
No signature of method: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue() is applicable for argument types: (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode, java.lang.Class)
```

Is there any way or workaround to get myarray object without using JsonNode?

(We are now using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind latest version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jackson Databind version 2.9.8.

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.8'
```

You need to locate `myarray` and then check if it is an array. After that you can proceed to traverse through its children. Where `data.json` is the file containing the JSON data.

### StationParser.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;

public class StationParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        InputStream ios = Library.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.json");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ArrayNode data = (ArrayNode) mapper.readTree(ios).get("myarray");
        Station[] stations = mapper.readValue(data.traverse(), Station[].class);

        for (Station station : stations) {
            System.out.println(station);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Station [id=123, title=my title, name=my name]
Station [id=456, title=my title 2, name=my name 2]
```

### Station.java

```
public class Station {
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Station [id=%s, title=%s, name=%s]", id, title, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the issue is when we serialise the array into MyClass Object.

       `def stations = mapper.readValue(node.get("myarray"), MyClass[].class);`
the issue at at the above line.